# We have Upgraded a windows service from. Net4.7.2 framework to. NetCore 6.0, We are encountering issue when we start the service through service.msc

Tags: .net, .net-core, c#-4.0

Error Details are as follows:

Application:Myservice.exe

CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2123.36311

.NET Version: 6.0.21

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ServiceController enables manipulating and accessing Windows services and it is not applicable for other operating systems.

at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase..ctor()

at Myservice..ctor() in C:\Dev\Visual Studio\MyServiceProcessor\Myservice.cs:line 17

at Myservice.Program.Main() in C:\Dev\Visual Studio\MyServiceProcessor\Myservice\Program.cs:line 22

We have installed   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController from NuGet package in order to resolve the issue but no luck.

Comment: Does your startup configuration include a call to `.UseWindowsService()`? You'll need to post some sample code in order to get any useful help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.